# Override the method of packing HTTP form-urlencoded parameters in Meteor HTTP call

Tags: http, meteor, url-encoding

I'm using Meteor to consume a remote API. One of the endpoints of this API requires an (ordered) array of credentials, so the data would look like

```
{
  "country": "de",
  "credentials": ["admin", "password"],
  "whatever": "whatever"
}
```

When I provide this plain-object as the value to `param` property of `HTTP.post` like this

```
HTTP.post('https://api.whatever.org/whatever', {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic ".concat(...)
  },
  params: {
    "country": "de",
    "credentials": ["admin", "password"],
    "whatever": "whatever"
  }
});
```

then the parameters are packed this way:

```
country=de
credentials=admin,password
whatever=whatever
```

but they should be packed this way:

```
country=de
credentials=admin
credentials=password
whatever=whatever
```

I tried using a `Content-Type` header but it didn't help.

I tried using `content` and `data` instead of `params` with different outcomes and then ended concatenating all the values into a query string an putting it into `content` property. But this isn't really a nice piece of code and surely not one that is easy to maintain.

I've read docs but haven't found anything that would help.

Where should I look for the information regarding this topic? Is there a better way to override the way `HTTP.post` (or, in general, `HTTP.call`) computes the body of the query to send?

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I look for the information regarding this topic?

In the source code.

I know nothing about Meteor, but I’m looking into [its source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/2fd00e58ba651c58b5705ce462c6e018e5249119/packages/url/url_common.js#L8) and I see no public hook which could help you. Of course, you can replace `URL._encodeParams` with your own function, but that is less maintainable than submitting the encoded params as raw data.